# Display "Message Sent" alert in same colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using a colorbox to send questions to users. So at the bottom of the colorbox there is ASK button. When user press ASK question is sent. But there is no way for user to know that question is sent. Is there a way i can show message sent in same colorobx or open new colorbox right after message is sent? Also is there a way to make this message sent colorbox disappear after 10 seconds or so? I know i am asking couple questions but been researching for this whole day and cant find solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ColorBox plugin developed by Jack Moore of [ColorPowered](http://colorpowered.com/), then you could consider the following approach:

- use ColorBox's **iFrame** option to open an HTML page in the colorbox. That way, you'll have a lot of control about what happens on any given user interaction.
- Consider using Jquery (since you tagged this question with it) to trap the user click on the ASK button. Upon a click reveal a simple DIV styled to indicate that the question has been sent/received or whatever. Investigate the **.hide()** and **.show()** functions.
- It is also easy with Jquery's timeout features to make the acknowledgement disappear after a set duration. Investigate the **fadeIn()** and **fadeOut()** functions; (using these will obviate the need for using .show and .hide).

Regards,  Kevin M.